# Exit my BlackJack game

Tags: python

need some help exiting this game... It almost works the way I want it to, but if the player chooses "stay" as an option, while the house also chooses the option to "stay", then the game is just in an endless loop of staying until the user hits. I want the game to go to the 
`end_game(house_cards, new_player_hand)` function if the house and player decide to both stay at the same time. Also, if you see any other stupid errors or total inefficiencies in this program please tell me! Also sorry for the lack of readability... I need to add some comments!

```
import random
import numpy as np
def start_game():
    while True:
        Choice = raw_input("Do you Want to Play Black Jack? Y/N?\n").lower()
        if Choice == "y":
            shuffle(cards)
            deal(cards)
            player_turn(player_hand, cards)
        elif Choice == "n":
            exit()
        else:
            print "Please Choose Y or N"
def shuffle(cards):
    cards = [x for x in cards for y in range(4)]
    return cards


def player_turn(player_hand, cards):
    Choice_1 = raw_input("Would you like to hit, fold, or stay?\n").lower()
    if Choice_1 == "hit":
        hit(player_hand,cards)
    elif Choice_1 == "fold":
        print "Lame... You lose!"
        start_game()
    elif Choice_1 == "stay":
        house_ai(house_hand, cards)
    else:
        print "please choose to hit, fold, or stay\n"
    return player_hand, cards

def hit(player_hand, cards): 
    global new_player_hand
    rand_card = random.choice(cards)
    player_hand.append(rand_card)
    new_player_hand = player_hand
    print new_player_hand
    if np.sum(new_player_hand) > 21:
        print "You went over 21!"
    elif np.sum(player_hand) < 21:
        Choice_3 = raw_input("Would you like to hit or stay?\n").lower()
        if Choice_3 == "hit":
            hit(new_player_hand, cards)
        elif Choice_3 == "stay":
            print "Okay house turn!"
            house_ai(house_hand, cards)
        else:
            print "Choose hit or stay"
    elif np.sum(new_player_hand) == 21:
        print "You win!"
    return player_hand, cards , new_player_hand


def house_ai(house_hand, cards):
    global house_cards
    house_cards = np.sum(house_hand)
    if house_cards == 17: #house stays
        print "House stays."    
        player_turn(player_hand, cards)
    elif house_cards > 17 and house_cards <21:
        print "House stays."
        player_turn(player_hand, cards)
    elif house_cards < 17:
        print "House hits."
        house_less(house_hand, house_cards, cards)  
    return house_hand, house_cards, cards

def house_less(house_hand, house_cards, cards):
    if np.sum(house_hand) < 17:
        new_card = random.sample(set(cards), 1)
        print "The House hits."
        house_hand.extend(new_card)
        print house_hand
        house_less(house_hand, house_cards, cards)
    elif np.sum(house_hand) > 21:
        print "The House hits."
        house_greater(house_cards)
    elif np.sum(house_hand) == 17:
        player_turn(player_hand, cards)
    elif np.sum(house_hand) > 17 and house_cards < 21:
        player_turn(player_hand, cards)
    elif np.sum(house_hand) == 21:
        house_wins(house_cards)
    return house_hand, house_cards, cards

def house_greater(house_cards):
    print "You Win! The house went over 21!"
    return house_cards

def end_game(house_cards, new_player_hand):
    if new_player_hand > house_cards:
        print "YOU WIN! YOU HAVE HIGHER CARDS THAN THE HOUSE"
    elif new_player_hand < house_cards:
        print "YOU LOSE! HOUSE HAS HIGGHER CARDS"
    else:
        assert False

def house_wins(house_cards):
    if house_cards == 21:
        print house_hand
        print " Sorry the House wins!"
    return house_cards


def deal(cards):
    global player_hand
    global house_hand
    player_hand = random.sample(set(cards),2)
    house_hand = random.sample(set(cards),2)
    print "Here are your cards!", player_hand


    return player_hand
    return house_hand
cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10 , 10, 10, 10]

start_game()
```

Thanks for any responses guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at how I implemented a blackjack simulator here: https://github.com/skyl/broken-knuckles

Your first problem appears to be that you are letting the player hit, then the dealer can hit, then the player can hit again? That's not how blackjack works. Each player plays completely before the dealer plays completely. So, once the dealer is done, you end the game and see who won. When the house stays, the game is over.

Comment: Wow thats right... I totally forgot that is how the game goes... probably should of researched it a bit more.   I guess that actually solves my question, Thanks! Also, your simulator is great. I need to learn how to take a more object oriented approach. If you have any tips you'd like to throw my way they would be greatly appreciated.